# Using AWS Java S3 SDK TransferManager to resume an upload from a SFTP stream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, spring-integration-sftp, awss3transfermanager, s3transfermanager

Currently, I am triggering an upload from an SFTP server to S3 using AWS's TransferManager in Java's S3 SDK. The way I trigger this upload is given below:

(pseudocode...)

```
    @Autowired
    TransferManager transferManager;

    @Autowired
    SftpStreamFactory sftpStreamFactory;

    SftpStream sftpStream = sftpStreamFactory.createStream(filePath);
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentLength(sftpStream.getSizeBytes());
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, sftpStream.getStream(), objectMetadata);
    putObjectRequest.setGeneralProgressListener(new UploadBeginEndNotificationListener(uploadRequest, statusNotifier));
    
    transferManager.upload(putObjectRequest);
```

and here is the definition for `SftpStream`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SftpStreamFactory {

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class SftpStream {
    private final long sizeBytes;
    private final InputStream stream;
}

private final SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpTemplate;
private final SftpProperties sftpProperties;

public SftpStream createStream(Path relativePath) {
    return sftpTemplate.<SftpStream, ChannelSftp>executeWithClient(session -> createStream(session, relativePath));
}

SftpStream createStream(ChannelSftp channelSftp, Path relativePath) {

    String path = sftpProperties.getRoot().resolve(relativePath).toString();

    try {
        SftpATTRS fileAttrs = channelSftp.lstat(path);
        long size = fileAttrs.getSize();
        return new SftpStream(size, channelSftp.get(path));
    }
    catch (SftpException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(new NestedIOException("SFTP Error", e));
    }
}
```

}

This method of upload works fine. However, if a multipart upload is paused/cancelled/otherwise aborted in the middle, we would like to pick up where we left off instead of restarting over again. We are aware of the TransferManagers `resumeUpload` method that takes a `PersistableUpload`.

However, in the javadoc for `PersistableUpload`, it is expecting a `file` path to be passed in the constructor, and later tries to created a `File` object from it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/PersistableUpload.html

What we are wondering is, is there anyway to resume an upload without having this file object, which we cannot get from our `ChannelSftp`? That is, can we resume an upload from a stream instead of a file? Or would we have to switch to using the low level s3 api's to perform such a resume. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Edit - Looked into a bit more and even passing an UploadId for an already existing upload, the doUpload method will throw Exception if there's no file. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you take a look at this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/pausing-and-resuming-transfers-using-transfer-manager/ ?
I am almost certain that you can do it, but I don't have the time right now to put together an example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, no, you can not resume upload without the file, but there's a workaround for similar case of yours:

**#SUCCESS TO PAUSE BEFORE ABORTED**

1. If and only if, before any interruption occurred, try to pause the connection

```
boolean forceCancel = true;
PauseResult<PersistableUpload> pauseResult = myUpload.tryPause(forceCancel);
```

2. Save `info to resume` data to file

```
PersistableUpload persistableUpload = pauseResult.getInfoToResume();

File f = new File("UNIQUE-ID-FOR-UPLOADED-FILE"); //blob
if (!f.exists())
    f.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

// Serialize the persistable upload to the file.
persistableUpload.serialize(fos);
fos.close();
```

3. Continue sometimes later

```
TransferManager tm = new TransferManager();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("UNIQUE-ID-FOR-UPLOADED-FILE"));

// Deserialize PersistableUpload information from disk.
PersistableUpload persistableUpload = PersistableTransfer.deserializeFrom(fis);

// Call resumeUpload with PersistableUpload.
tm.resumeUpload(persistableUpload);

fis.close();
```

**#SAVE STREAM TO MAINTAIN FILE IF SOMETHING'S HAPPENED (e.g. JVM Crash)**

Use `S3SyncProgressListener` to `TransferManager#upload` to persist every change and serializes the data to disk.

```
transferManager.upload(putObjectRequest, new S3SyncProgressListener() {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @Override
    public void onPersistableTransfer(final PersistableTransfer persistableTransfer) {

       executor.submit(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                  File f = new File("UNIQUE-ID-FOR-UPLOADED-FILE");
                  if (!f.exists()) {
                      f.createNewFile();
                  }
                  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                  persistableTransfer.serialize(fos);
                  fos.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException("Unable to persist transfer to disk.", e);
              }
          }
       });
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.